# echo "minor number" > misc char driver - gets truncated

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a misc char driver and when I echo the minor number of the driver to misc character driver it does not receive the first digit.

The write function is like this,

```
static ssize_t hellowld_write(struct file *file, const char *buf,size_t len, 
                loff_t *ppos)
{
    pr_debug("In hellowld_write len %d buf %s \n",len,buf);
    minor[0] = '\0';    
    snprintf(minor, 20,"%d", hellowld_device.minor);
    strncpy(inputminor, buf,len);
    pr_debug("In hellowld_write -- minor %s -- recvNum  %s end\n",minor, inputminor);
    pr_debug("In hellowld_write -- strlen minor %d -- strlen inputminor  %d end\n", strlen(minor), strlen(inputminor));
    if( strncmp(minor, inputminor, strlen(minor)) ==  0)
    {
        pr_debug("In hellowld_write -- strcmp passed \n");
        return strlen(minor);   
    }
    else 
    {
        pr_debug("In hellowld_write -- strcmp failed \n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }   
}
```

When I do,
echo "54" >/dev/hellowld

```
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382424] In hellowld_write len 1 buf 
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382424] 
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382424] o
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382437] In hellowld_write -- minor 54 -- recvNum  
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382437] 4
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382437]  end
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382444] In hellowld_write -- strlen minor 2 -- strlen inputminor  3 end
Dec 31 11:36:40 pavan-linux kernel: [16981.382448] In hellowld_write -- strcmp failed
```

echo "22" >/dev/hellowld

```
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.356993] In hellowld_write len 3 buf 22
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.356993] 
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.356993] o
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.357011] In hellowld_write -- minor 54 -- recvNum  22
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.357011]  end
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.357017] In hellowld_write -- strlen minor 2 -- strlen inputminor  3 end
Dec 31 11:36:52 pavan-linux kernel: [16993.357021] In hellowld_write -- strcmp failed
```

why is that when I echo the minor number, the data received in the hellowld_write is truncated ?

Comment: Your function `hellowld_write` does 2 bad things: it accesses `buf` directly (without `copy_from_user`) and doesn't return a value. Please, use this function's implementation in your tests: `pr_debug("In hellowld_write len %d\n", len); return len;`.

Comment: Can you please post your full driver code?

Comment: Tsyvarev's comment helped